# JSON AJAX Post 403 forbidden error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, spring

Hi I just started learning Spring, AJAX, JSON. I have been getting an error when i try to post a message back.

**messages.jsp**

```
function success(data) {
    $("#form" + data.target).toggle();
    $("#alert" + data.target).text("Message sent.")
    startTimer();

}

function error(data) {
    alert("Error sending message");
} 

function sendMessage(i, name, email){
    var text = $("#textbox" + i).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: '<c:url value="/sendmessage" />',
        data: JSON.stringify({"target": i, "text": text, "name": name, "email": email}),
        success: success,
        error: error,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });

}

function showMessages(data){

    $("div#messages").html("");

    for(var i=0; i<data.messages.length; i++) {
        var message = data.messages[i];

        var messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
        messageDiv.setAttribute("class", "message");

        var subjectSpan = document.createElement("span");
        subjectSpan.setAttribute("class", "subject");
        subjectSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message.subject));

        var contentSpan = document.createElement("span");
        contentSpan.setAttribute("class", "contentText");
        contentSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message.content));

        var nameSpan = document.createElement("span");
        nameSpan.setAttribute("class", "nameSpan");
        nameSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode("From: "+ message.name + '('));

        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("class", "replylink");
        link.setAttribute("href", "#");
        link.setAttribute("onClick", "showReply(" + i + ")");
        link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message.email));
        nameSpan.appendChild(link);
        nameSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(")"));

        var alertSpan = document.createElement("span");
        alertSpan.setAttribute("class", "alert");
        alertSpan.setAttribute("id", "alert" + i);          

        var replyForm = document.createElement("form");
        replyForm.setAttribute("class", "replyForm");
        replyForm.setAttribute("id", "form" + i);

        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.setAttribute("class", "replyArea");
        textarea.setAttribute("id", "textbox" + i);


        var replyButton = document.createElement("input");
        replyButton.setAttribute("class", "replyButton");
        replyButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
        replyButton.setAttribute("value", "reply");
        replyButton.onclick = function(j, name, email) {
            return function() {
                sendMessage(j, name, email);
            }
        }(i, message.name, message.email);

        replyForm.appendChild(textarea);
        replyForm.appendChild(replyButton);

        messageDiv.appendChild(subjectSpan);
        messageDiv.appendChild(contentSpan);
        messageDiv.appendChild(nameSpan);
        messageDiv.appendChild(alertSpan);
        messageDiv.appendChild(replyForm);


        $("div#messages").append(messageDiv);
    }
}
```

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sendmessage", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> sendMessages(Principal principal, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> data){

    String text = (String)data.get("text");
    String name = (String)data.get("name");
    String email = (String)data.get("email");
    Integer target = (Integer)data.get("target");

    System.out.println(name + " , " + email + " , " + text);

    Map<String, Object> returnVal = new HashMap<String, Object>();      
    returnVal.put("success", true);
    returnVal.put("target", target);

    return returnVal;
}
```

I have tried many different things to solve this problem but nothing is working, I can't post the message.

Any help or reason why I keep getting this error?

> jquery.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/spring/sendmessage 403
>   (Forbidden) send @ jquery.js:4 ajax @ jquery.js:4 sendMessage @
>   messagesView:32 (anonymous function) @ messagesView:90

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae7Kg.png)

Comment: What about your security configuration?

Comment: I have set the security to isAuthenticated likes this:      <security:intercept-url pattern="/messagesView" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/sendmessage" access="isAuthenticated()" />

Comment: Have you logged in your application before the sending request? If you have a security problem you can check with setting permitAll for one time. If is it work when you set permitAll that means you have a security problem.

Comment: Yeah I am logged in I keep getting the error message

Comment: I keep getting this error -POST http://localhost:8080/spring/sendmessage 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Can you add your post header to 'Content-Type' 'application/json'

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I saw that, you gave right parameters to jquery Ajax. I can't find answer with this informations. Good luck :)

Comment: What response are you expecting from the server for your sendMessage function?

Comment: when the the user enters a messages and clicks reply, it should be returning a success message. But I keep getting the error alert with the error I have mentioned above appearing the developer tools console in chrome. I will edit my post and add code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, you need to add the CSRF headers into the AJAX POST request. Take a look at [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html). I'm not at my development system at the moment so can't post an example, but using the info from this page worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to work this out since yesterday finally working.

Comment: @JJ9999 could you share the final solution as advised by Cliff? I am having the same problem and since I am new to JS and AJAX I am facing difficult wrapping my head around this problem

Answer (score 0):

step-1:
put a id to the form --->

```
<form id='formid' ....>
```

step-2:
pass the form as serialize form --->

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: '<c:url value="/sendmessage" />',
        data: ('#formid').serialize(),
        success: success,
        error: error,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
 });
```